# Round double off with 2 digits after comma - C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have the number 12.1799999 and it should become 12.17
How does it work in c#?

Comment: If you intent to round down, then use `Math.Floor(number)`

Comment: but if i use it the number becomes 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = 12.1799999M;
n = Math.Floor(n * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intent to round down, then use `Math.Floor(number, amountOfDecimals)`

`amountOfDecimals` should be 2 in your case

Comment: No overload for method 'Floor' takes 2 arguments

Comment: The function floor takes only one argument

Comment: I see, I thought `Math.Floor()` had a decimal overload, like `Math.Round()`